# Django - share media files during development

Tags: django, git, ubuntu, django-media

I want developers to use the same development database while developing a `Django` project so I've created a remote server with `Ubuntu 18.04`, created `Postgres` database and allowed remote access.

The problem is that there are missing pictures - `media` directory is in `.gitignore` because of production server. How I make `media` being shared (and editable) so any developer can see any image and assign image to object?

I was thinking about sharing it through git or to store media on production server where `Postgres` is but not sure how and if it's the best way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you configure your project to store media files remotely — i.e., in an Amazon S3 instance? That way all of your developers could access them.

Comment: Sam's suggestion is a good one. Another is to take a step back and ask why you're forcing your developers to all use the same database and `media/` directory. I can't think of a valid reason to impose this on them.

Answer (score 0):

Funny setup...

2 thoughts:

1. Shared DB sure you have your reasons but why are you running a centralized dev server vs having developers run local and gain access to terminal logs with a `DATABASE` configuration that points to the remote DB?
2. You can stash an empty `media` directory or any other -- description on how at [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)